# Rewriting Include() to a linq join

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, compiled-query

As it's (at this moment) impossibe to use Include() in a compiled query, I'm trying to rewrite them to joins. But it doesn't seem to work out quite as I would want it to.

Say I have this relation:

```
Order              OrderState
Id                 Id   
OrderStateId       Description
```

Now I used to fetch the description as follows:

```
var q = (from o in context.Orders
         where o.Id = orderId
         select o).Include("OrderState");
```

I've tried rewriting this as:

```
var q = (from o in context.Orders
         join st in context.OrderStates on o.OrderStateId equals st.Id
         where o.Id = orderId
         select o);
```

But the OrderState is still null in my resultset. How would I go about fixing this (in a way that;s acceptable for compiled query)?

Comment: @hvd and the Oops is for me now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't use `.Include`, you need to actually include `o.OrderState` somewhere in the result, so how about this?

```
var q = (from o in context.Orders
         where o.Id = orderId
         select new { Order = o, o.OrderState });
```

`o.Order.OrderState` should get hooked up to `o.OrderState` without extra help for each result in `q`.